# "great for the chase" vs "expert in the chase"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

"Great for the chase" vs "Expert in the chase"

I found these two clauses on the same page of The Iliad:

> Then Menelaus son of Atreus caught the brilliant hunter Scamandrius with his sharp spear. Scamandrius was a great man **for the chase**, who had been taught by the goddess Artemis...

Then in a note below I read:

> Scamandrius, expert **in the chase**, is killed by Menelaus.

What's exactly the difference between the two?

Comment: If you are _a great man for_ or _a great one for_ something, you are very keen on it (and probably very good at it). The phrase you have used in the heading, _expert for_, is not idiomatic - it's _expert in_ or _at_.

Comment: @chasly from UK. I edited the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"great man" is a noun.

In this context, "expert" is an adjective (some would say it's an adverb).

Compare:

> *Is John good at tennis?*
>
> *He is an expert* (in the game of tennis)
>
> Here 'expert' is a noun.

> *Is John good at tennis?*
>
> *He is expert* (at the game of tennis)
>
> Here 'expert' qualifies John's quality of playing.

**EDIT**

"A good man in X"  is different from "A good man for X"

*John is a good man in a difficult situation.* (This mean that John is capable and you want to have him on your team when things get tough)

*John is a good man for hunting.* (This mean that John likes hunting and will always accept an invitation to go hunting)